# OAUTH2(OPENID Connect) + MVC 5. refresh token issue

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5, google-glass, owin, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm looking for any useful suggestion with regards to obtaining `refresh_token` using OWIN libs.

I follow article http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

all stuff works sweet. but no way, at least I don't know the way, to retrieve `refresh_token`

I've tried to add "access_offline" to initial request, nothing useful. I definitely do something wrong.

Why do I need it? - I'm trying to chain functionality of `Google Glass + MVC5 + OWIN`.

p.s. I will appreciate any link to working sample built using Google.Api.Auth.

Thanks.

Comment: I know it might be too late, but take alook at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894789/how-to-renew-the-access-token-using-the-refresh-token/24972426#24972426

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look in the following blogpost:
http://peleyal.blogspot.com/2014/01/aspnet-mvc-with-google-openid-and-oauth.html 
And, you can find a working sample code in https://github.com/peleyal/peleyal/tree/master/Google.Apis.Sample.MVC.

Comment: thanks, good post. One question: I cannot understand the design idea about making DataStore as FileStore. Do you know any EF implementation  for instance, as you mentioned slightly in your blog?

Comment: One of my next tasks is to have a EF implementation. Remember that it's a open source project, so if you come to a good solution, let me know, I'll be happy to take a look in that and add it to the repository. For now I decided to implement only the very basic for .net 4.0, WP and WinRT. I opened a new issue for that one - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=453

Comment: I got the point, thanks. I've tried your sample, and still stuck on getting `access/refresh tokens`. As I can see for example FileDataStore, same something like url `http://localhost:49244/Home/DriveAsync86747631`. Can't figure out what is this. I definitely can't pass it to google MirrorApi for .net. any ideas?

Comment: I'm saving in the state parameter (see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp), the URL to go back after all the OAuth 2.0 flow is done. I'm adding some random numbers to the end of the URL (see https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Auth/OAuth2/Web/AuthorizationCodeWebApp.cs#115), because I want to be sure that I was the one that started the OAuth 2.0 flow and no one else.

Comment: I figured it out. just added.  `properties.Dictionary.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("access_type","offline"));` into `ExecuteResult` method of `ChallengeResult` class.

Comment: Another question. I'm looking to your implementaiton of DriveSync.  and trying to figure out the goal of AuthorizationCodeMvcApp. Do I need to do a call into each action? is it just code for refreshing token each time? What is the best place to hold this code? maybe attribute or overriding method like BeginExecute,etc.? thanks

Comment: Take a look at - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Auth.Mvc4/OAuth2/Mvc/AuthorizationCodeMvcApp.cs. As you can see it just simplify the code for you, and set the state parameter, so the after the OAuth 2.0 flow is done, Google will return back to your page.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to play with fresh `Mirror Api`, maybe half a day I was receiving correct complex `AuthResult.Credential` object with Access/Refresh keys calling `AuthorizationCodeMvcApp.AuthorizeAcync` method. I was using it as input parameter for `MirrorService.HttpClientInitializer`. But now it does not work.For some reason I get only only Url. do you have any suggestion? Is there any chance to athorize on Google Glass using easier flow?

Answer (score 1):

Yea, there's an open issue related to this in the Katana project:

https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/227

In short, it needs to be easier.

Comment: Thanks, useful link. Unfortunately, I have tried as suggested in comments.nothing changed, also tried 3.0-alpha - no luck. 
Feeling like a bit disappointed about looking to such big framework as katana owin, without obvious things like retrieving keys in easy and flexible way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code like this

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
    ClientSecret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET",
    AccessType = "offline",
    Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
    {
        OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
        {
            TimeSpan expiryDuration = context.ExpiresIn ?? new TimeSpan();
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:tokens:google:email", context.Email));
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:tokens:google:url", context.GivenName));
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.RefreshToken))
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:tokens:google:refreshtoken", context.RefreshToken));
            }
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:tokens:google:accesstoken", context.AccessToken));
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:tokens:google:accesstokenexpiry", DateTime.Now.Add(expiryDuration).ToString()));

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
});
```