# How to renew the access token using the refresh token?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5, google-oauth, owin

I am using **ASP.NET MVC 5** with **OWIN**.

I have done a lot of research and haven't found how to renew the access token using the refresh token.

My scenario is: The first time the user accesses my app, he or she grants access to the account I read the refresh token returned from the API. When the users come back to my app, I need to refresh the access token based on the "Refresh Token".

Could anybody provide some code?

Here is what I've achieved till now:

**Startup.Auth.cs:**

```
    var googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
    {
        Caption = "Google+",
        ClientId = Parameters.Instance.Authentication.oAuth.GooglePlus.ClientId,
        ClientSecret = Parameters.Instance.Authentication.oAuth.GooglePlus.ClientSecret,
        CallbackPath = new PathString("/oauth-login-return"),
        Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnAuthenticated = async context =>
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)));
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, context.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)));
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("picture", context.User.GetValue("picture").ToString()));
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("profile", context.User.GetValue("profile").ToString()));
                context.Identity.AddClaim(
                    new Claim(Parameters.Instance.Authentication.oAuth.GooglePlus.AccessTokenClaimType,
                        context.AccessToken));
            }
        }
    };
    googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
    googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
```

**AuthenticationController:**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{
    RedirectIfAuthenticated();

    return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Content("~/oauth-login-callback"));
}

[ActionName("oauth-login-back")]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
}

// Used for XSRF protection when adding external logins
private const string XsrfKey = "XsrfId";

private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    }
}

private class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
{
    public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri)
        : this(provider, redirectUri, null)
    {
    }

    private ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId)
    {
        LoginProvider = provider;
        RedirectUri = redirectUri;
        UserId = userId;
    }

    private string LoginProvider { get; set; }

    private string RedirectUri { get; set; }

    private string UserId { get; set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
        if (UserId != null)
        {
            properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
        }
        context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you getting the OAuth Bearer token?

Comment: @ErikPhilips I have inserted some code excerpt. Please, check it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OWIN Security - How to Implement OAuth2 Refresh Tokens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637674/owin-security-how-to-implement-oauth2-refresh-tokens)

Comment: @erikphilips sorry erik, but i didn't get the point after reading that link. Am I supposed to build a oauth authentication provider yet I'm using OWIN GOOGLE? Thx.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This question isn't duplicate AT ALL. I hope this help others not spending days like I have spent.

After almost 4 days I have found out how to get a fresh access token in the google api using OWIN.

I'm going to post the solution, but first, I MUST say that what helped me to start getting a clue about my error was setting up the Debug Symbols for the Katana project. See this link:
http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/VisualStudio

This image show how to configure Debug Symbols Servers.
[image]

And this one shows the Katana Debug Symbols being loaded.
[image]

After that, I found out that my problem was that Google API was returning 403: Forbidden

"Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project"

Then, found on stack overflow this post: 
["Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014129/access-not-configured-please-use-google-developers-console-to-activate-the-api)

more specifically this Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24401189/833846

After that, I went to Google Developers Console and setup up Google+ API

And then, voillá! It worked.

Now, the code to get a fresh access token using the refresh token (I haven't found any way to accomplish that using the OWIN API).

```
public static class TokenValidator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Obtém um novo access token na API do google.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clientId"></param>
    /// <param name="clientSecret"></param>
    /// <param name="refreshToken"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static GoogleRefreshTokenModel ValidateGoogleToken(string clientId, string clientSecret, string refreshToken)
    {
        const string url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

        var parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "refresh_token"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("refresh_token", refreshToken)
        };

        var content = GetContentAsync(url, "POST",  parameters);

        var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleRefreshTokenModel>(content);

        return token;
    }

    private static string GetContentAsync(string url, 
        string method = "POST",
        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters = null)
    {
        return method == "POST" ? PostAsync(url, parameters) : GetAsync(url, parameters);
    }

    private static string PostAsync(string url, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters = null)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(url);

        var request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        var postParameters = GetPostParameters(parameters);

        var bs = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postParameters);
        using (var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            reqStream.Write(bs, 0, bs.Length);
        }

        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            var jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();

            return jsonResponse;
        }
    }

    private static string GetPostParameters(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters = null)
    {
        var postParameters = string.Empty;
        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            postParameters += string.Format("&{0}={1}", parameter.Key,
                HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(parameter.Value));
        }
        postParameters = postParameters.Substring(1);

        return postParameters;
    }

    private static string GetAsync(string url, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters = null)
    {
        url += "?" + GetQueryStringParameters(parameters);

        var forIdsWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)forIdsWebRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var data = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
            {
                var jsonResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();

                return jsonResponse;
            }
        }
    }

    private static string GetQueryStringParameters(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters = null)
    {
        var queryStringParameters = string.Empty;
        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            queryStringParameters += string.Format("&{0}={1}", parameter.Key,
                HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(parameter.Value));
        }
        queryStringParameters = queryStringParameters.Substring(1);

        return queryStringParameters;
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT 1:** To get a refresh token you must set the "access_type" to "offline" in the "**ExecuteResult**" method, this way:

```
properties.Dictionary["access_type"] = "offline";
```

**IMPORTANT 2:** Once you get your refresh token, you must store it and in some secure source. Google API won't issue you a new refresh token, unless you set "approval_prompt" to "force" before you call the line (in the same method):

```
context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
```

I also recommend taking a look at:

[**Google API Offline Access**](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline)

[**Google OAUTH 2.0 Playground**](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

[**Google API Discovery Check**](https://discovery-check.appspot.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Spent the last two days figuring out how to renew the access token myself. The answer is posted in another thread here:

[How Google API V 3.0 .Net library and Google OAuth2 Handling refresh token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26098009/how-google-api-v-3-0-net-library-and-google-oauth2-handling-refresh-token/31843907#31843907)