# MVC 5 SPA Application Google Authentication token handling

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5

Starting with Rick Anderson's great tutorial [MVC 5 App with Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google OAuth2 Sign-on](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on), using the Google Authentication particularly...

I extended the scope of Google Authentication to include the DriveAPI. That part all works fine and Fiddler shows the googleapi access_token coming back.

I now want to provide the google api token to my javascript code so I can call the Google drive api with my access token directly.

I can get the token from the GoogleoAuth2AuthenticationProvider

```
GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions googleOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions() {
            ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"],
            ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"],
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
            Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider() {
                OnAuthenticated = async context => {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(GoogleApiAccessTokenClaimType, context.AccessToken));
                }
            },
        };
```

Clearly I need to store it somewhere.  I thought that the claims were automatically persisted in the .AspNetApplicationCookie, and even though this cookie is read again I can't see an easy way to retrieve any claims I've added.

That makes me feel like I should store it AspNetUser tables.  But that seems redundant if it is available from the cookie once it's read and decrypted.

Now say I have the token, how should I communicate it to my javascript.  I've been just sending it down with the page in a  block.  Dominick Baier said that was ok.  But I still wonder if I should consider another method.

So my question in summary is...

1. How should I be getting my token for the drive api? (I think I've
   got    this working)
2. Where should I keep it?
3. How should I expose it to my javascript code?

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

These other two questions and discussion cover most of the nitty-gritty.

Really helpful.  Especially the symbol setup.  (A little easier to work with than Reflector generated pdbs)

[questions/24894789/how-to-renew-the-access-token-using-the-refresh-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894789/how-to-renew-the-access-token-using-the-refresh-token)

Somewhat helpful, in the ballpark.

[questions/20637674/owin-security-how-to-implement-oauth2-refresh-tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637674/owin-security-how-to-implement-oauth2-refresh-tokens)